# com_error (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147352561), None)

Tags: python, excel, vba

I'm writing a python script that interfaces with a VBA project and I've encountered this error:

```
C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py in Add(self, Type, Operator, Formula1, Formula2, String, TextOperator, DateOperator, ScopeType)

com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2147352561), None)
```

I got the error when running this code:

```py
import xlwings as xw  # (very old) version 0.7.2
wb = xw.Workbook.active()
sh = xw.Sheet.active()
xw.Range("$1:$500").xl_range.FormatConditions.Add(2, Formula1='CELL("protect", A1)=1')
```

I've looked at documentation and examples,  searched for the error codes, and confirmed that the equivalent VBA code runs.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to use positional instead of keyword arguments. The second argument in the solution is a dummy value (0) that is ignored for this combination of options. Strangely, VBA allows keyword arguments.

before:

```py
xw.Range("$1:$500").xl_range.FormatConditions.Add(2, Formula1='CELL("protect", A1)=1')
```

after:

```py
xw.Range("$1:$500").xl_range.FormatConditions.Add(2, 0,'CELL("protect", A1)=1')`
```

The second error code `-2147352561` means "Parameter not optional." in at least one context:
https://python-win32.python.narkive.com/kO1Lp4qA/client-side-com-problems-with-byref-parameters